# Viewing .html from a Mac on an iphone locally?

Tags: iphone, xcode, mobile, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I'm coding a personal website on my mac and I'd like to view it in 'real-time' (even if that means hitting reload) on an actual connected iPhone. Is this possible? I've connected the iPhone to the mac and enabled the Web Inspector in Safari (iOS) and the Developer menu on the Mac. The iPhone is listed in on the Mac's Safari Developer menu.

Once I have the local html (which loads css and js) open in the Mac's Safari window, how can I then open the html (with css and js) in iPhone's Safari?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While on the same network, try going to safari on your iPhone and enter your host name

```
http://<name>.local
```

or use your IP address

```
http://5.2.3.5
```

Comment: That's not working. I have the `file:///Users/me/webper/new/index.html` as the address of the page in Safari on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options.

The easy one is CodeKit, it has a built-in server and other devices on the same network will be able to view your files, for more details check the 'Server Popover' section on https://codekitapp.com/help/browser-refreshing/

If you don't mind using command line and an app like Terminal or iTerm, here's another method that uses NodeJS to setup your local server.

Note: You may already have some of what you need installed on your Mac. To test if NodeJS is installed, in Terminal run `node -v`, if you see a vesion number then you can probably skip the first step.  And if you run the command `http-server` and get something other than command not found, you can probably skip the third step.

The following should work starting from scratch on a Mac or Windows (with an alternate command line app).

(1) Go to https://nodejs.org and download and install NodeJS

(2) In Terminal or iTerm, cd to your project's directory

(3) In Terminal, run the command  `npm install -g http-server`

(4) If everything goes according to plan, you can now start your local server with the terminal command `http-server`

You'll be notified that the server has started and URLs it's available on, eg

http://127.0.0.1:8080
or
http://192.168.2.12:8080

The first URL would be for the local mac (running terminal), other devices on the same network can use the second URL

To close your server, in terminal enter the command  `Ctrl + C`

There are lots of good online resources if you need extra help getting started with Node, here's one:
https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-nodejs-tutorial-mac-os-x/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load an html file that you've created on your Mac to your iPhone you'll need to do the following. From System Prefs > Sharing > Enable Web Sharing. Place the html file in your ~/Sites folder.

Go the the URL listed in the Web Sharing panel from your iPhone, while on the home network, and open the html file. It will load in Mobile Safari.